# Action class not working excel sheet data fetch

Tags: selenium-webdriver, action

Excel sheet 3row. I have try to run eclipse.
1st time is running properly,
But next or 2row action button not working in selenium.
Without action button not working because double click Functionality are there.

My code is: action.movetoElement(text). doubleClick().build(). Perform()
Try
Action().doubleClick (text). Perform()

Comment: Which selenium binding art? Java/Python/C#/VBA?